# Getting a picture from SD card and Camera

Tags: android, android-intent, media, android-camera

I'm currently having a standard image selection (from the SD card) dialog shown when firing off this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

This lists all the applications/activities that can return an image (such as Gallery).

In this same standard list, I also want to include an option that will start the Camera and return an image taken with it. The problem is I can't figure out how to do this in a non-custom way (building my own dialog with a custom layout, application image + title etc).

The Camera activity can be launched like this:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
URI pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("dummyPath"));
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
```

**Is there an intent that will allow me to select an image from the SD card or one taken with the Camera?**

Update: I have found a solution, will double check and post it here afterwards.

Comment: Can you please share solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have alert dialog to show options. 
Source code is given below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder getImageFrom = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            getImageFrom.setTitle("Select Image");
            final CharSequence[] opsChars = {"Take Picture", "Open Gallery"};
            getImageFrom.setItems(opsChars, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(which == 0){
                         File file = new File( _path );
                         outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);   

                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 7);
                    }else
                        if(which == 1){
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Open Gallery"), 6);
                        }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 6) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
         pickerImageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
         pickerImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
         System.gc();
           String filepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
           File imagefile = new File(filepath);
           try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPurgeable=true;
            options.inSampleSize =4;
            bi= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis,null,options);
            fis.close();
            Bitmap bitmapToRecycle = ((BitmapDrawable)pickerImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();  
            bitmapToRecycle.recycle();
            pickerImageView.setImageBitmap(bi); 
            pickerImageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            pickerImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           pickImageTextView.setText("");
        }
        else if(requestCode == 7){
            Log.i("return", "#####");
            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPurgeable=true;
            options.inSampleSize =4;
            //Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( _path, options );
             Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
             pickerImageView.setImageBitmap(photo); 
             pickerImageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
             pickerImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is precisely the situation I want to avoid: creating a custom dialog, it's messy and it takes time. If there's a standard (probably easier) solution, I want to use it.

Comment: I've tried your code and it doesn't seem to work. After taking a picture, the Camera activity just hangs there. How can I return to my activity? anything special that must be done?

Comment: onActivityResult() method code returns to activity. Here, m setting selected image to imageview.

Comment: I understand, but: clicking the option displays a dialog with a Camera option (correct). Clicking the camera option opens the Camera activity (correct). However: after clicking "Take Picture" within the Camera activity, nothing happens! wouldn't the normal behavior be to return to my activity, inside the method onActivityResult?

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/

Comment: apparently, you need to click a button that will "use" the recently taken picture on 2.2 devices. my other issue was caused by the fact that the image was indeed saved to the provided URI, BUT in this case the returned intent would be null on some devices. thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can add programmatically your image to gallery like this:

```
Intent media = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
```

//mCurrentPhotoPath is the path to image.

```
File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
media.setData(contentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(media);
```